# Binding datagrid and combobox to the same datasource

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I'm facing the following problem:

I have a **datagrid** on the first tab and **combobox** on the second. They both are bound to the same property - **FieldList** (**OneWay** for datagrid and **TwoWay** for combobox).

The point is that the user needs to be able to select item from the **combobox** on the seconds page, but when he does such thing - the **SelectedItem** in the **datagrid** on the first page is changing as well.

And my question is how to prevent this? I don't want to change selection in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need OneTime binding for the grid, rather than OneWay

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. Thought, i found the other way and the question is not relevant.